# .BackgroundColor does not change background color

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I'm creating a SWRevealView Controller and whenever I use self.view.backgroundColor or instantiate a new View Controller and use UIViewController.backgrounsColor it never changes the background color which always remains white. Does anyone know why this happens?

example code:

```
let background = UIView()
background.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 241/255, green: 241/255, blue: 242/255, alpha: 1)
tables.tableFooterView = background
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the frame to the View..
 Like:
`background.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)`
 Your `background`'s frame is zero if you only use `let background = UIView()`

Comment: Yes that works, do you know how to create a CGRect that fills whats remaining of the screen. In this case, this view serves as a footer to fill the screen with the correct color when there are not enough table rows

Comment: I am not clear whether you means to set the color of the view that contain a tableView. 
Actually 
1.you can set the view's backgroundcolor which add tableView as subView `view.addsubView: tableView` (check the frame first)
2. you can creat the tableView's `headerView` or `FooterView` by your self
3. change the `tableView background color` or `tableViewCell  background color`

Comment: Setting the color of the Table Footer or the view itself will both produce the same result. Changing the table views or cells background color will not work, because I'm also looking to remove the cell separators as well. Also since i am adding a UIView as the table footer self.view.backgroundColor will not work because the original view(table view) is completed by the footer. As a result I have to find a way to programmatically determine the bounds of the CGrect to fill the remaining space in my screen.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code?

Also, do you have any UIViews (or any subclass of) in front of the UIViewController that is the size of the UIViewController? If so, those views could be blocking the way, and therefore you would never see a change.

Also `UIViewController.backgroundColor` won't work, as UIViewController is not a view. So if you could post your code, I will provide a more direct answer, until then, this is the best answer I got.

**Edit**

You gave no frame to your view. I would look up the fundamentals of Swift Programming, up to, and including, the parts that include how to add elements to the UI. Would be incredibly helpful.

Comment: I have updated my post with some of my code. tables in the example is an IBOutlet of my tableView.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had a subview where the background colour didn't change, and it did not respond to buttons within this subview.

It confused me that the `frame` was all `0` and it still rendered to the screen.

All I had to do was add another constraint.